# Parameterized query which sends NULL value, with C# and SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql

I tried to pass some variables into a parameterized query but when the value is NULL it throws an exception that says the value is not provided.

How can I fix that without an if or something like that?

My code is this

```
var cmdPersona_Log = new SqlCommand();
cmdPersona_Log.Parameters.Clear();
cmdPersona_Log.Connection = mySqlConnection;
cmdPersona_Log.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmdPersona_Log.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO [Tomin].[TominRH].[Persona_Log] "
+ "([Id_Action],[Id_User],[Id_Date],[Id_Entidad],[Nombre],[Paterno],[Materno],[Sexo],[Id_Nacionalidad])"
+ " Values (1, 'Admin', @fecha, @id_entidad, @nombre, @paterno, @materno, 1, 52)";

cmdPersona_Log.Parameters.Add("@fecha", DateTime.Now);
cmdPersona_Log.Parameters.Add("@id_entidad", dbRow["CUENTA"]);
cmdPersona_Log.Parameters.Add("@nombre", nombre);
cmdPersona_Log.Parameters.Add("@paterno", paterno);
cmdPersona_Log.Parameters.Add("@materno", materno);

cmdPersona_Log.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: What's the field causing troubles?

Comment: @materno, the thing is, when I do the query without parameters there is no problem, but there will be some times that those parameters will be null

Comment: you should check if the parameter is != null before add it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will assume that your problem is that the underlying field doesn't support nulls. If this is the case, you could do something like this

```
cmdPersona_Log.Parameters.Add("@nombre", nombre ?? string.Empty);
cmdPersona_Log.Parameters.Add("@paterno", paterno ?? string.Empty); 
cmdPersona_Log.Parameters.Add("@materno", materno ?? string.Empty);
```

You'll be inserting an empty string in case you have a null using the [null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx).